# NextJs app hosted on Firebase gives "Application error: a server-side exception has occurred "

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, google-cloud-functions

I am building a NextJs app and I spent all of the past month having it deployed on Vercel and it was working fine with no problems. I decided to switch from Vercel to Firebase hosting as I am using Firestore but when I got to the deployment part it told me I must enable Blaze plan to be able to host my app. I upgraded the app but after I deployed the app wont load and it only gives "Application error: a server-side exception has occurred". I tried running the firebase emulator to see if its a problem with firebase itself but it ran locally without problems.

Update:

I think that the problem is from server components as when I commented any awaits for data fetching inside of my server components it kinda worked so how can I fix that
I tried checking the logs also but it only says error 500 with no extra information.

next.config

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    images: {
        remotePatterns: [
            {
                protocol: 'https',
                hostname: 'firebasestorage.googleapis.com'
            }
        ]
    },
    experimental: {
        serverComponentsExternalPackages: ['@sparticuz/chromium', 'puppeteer-core']
    }
};

export default nextConfig;
```

Comment: Can you share your app.yaml and next.config.js files?

Comment: I do not have an app.yaml in my project but I will share the next.config.js

Comment: is there any other additional telemetry you could add to catch the issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.